# Android studio: Why can't I reference a variable I've declared?

Tags: java, android, variables, int, declaration

Using an Android studio empty activity (or Blank activity) if I declare an int then want to initialise it on the next line it will not let me. eg:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     int n;
     n=1;   // generates a lint here and says unknown class 'n'

}
```

It sets a lint under n=1; and tells me "unknown class: 'n' "

...yet if I create a method I can initialise it in the method. eg:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     int n;

     public void test() {
          n=1;
     }

}
```

It will also allow me to declare an int THEN initialise it on the next line INSIDE the method. eg:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     public void test() {
          int n;
          n=1;
     }

}
```

Could someone please explain why I cannot reference a variable I have set inside the MainActivity class? Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you initialize on the same line

Comment: You cannot initialize a variable directly inside a class (unless it's the same line), or even call methods You need a method or constructor.

Comment: drwisdom, I just wanted to know why it can be done in a method, but not a class.

Answer (score 1):

It's just the way Java variable initialization works - you can initialize variable at the beginning of your class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     int n = 1;
     .....
     other methods
}
```

or inside a method or constructor:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     int n;

     public void test() {
          n=1;
          int a;
          a = 8;
     }
}
```

it has nothing to do with android, just plain Java.

you may read about that mechanizm [here](http://java.about.com/od/understandingdatatypes/a/declaringvars.htm) for example.

Comment: Thank you. It's as if it's procedural inside a method, but not a class.